# Filling GridView with ImageButtons using adapter doesn't work

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, android-imagebutton

I'm writing small game app for assignment, like "memory" game. I want to use GridView and put ImageButtons in it to show one image 9 times, and set onClickListener to show random number beneath each image. I set gridview in layout, used id to access it, set adapter to fill it, but it doesn't work, and I get no error. Also, I tried to figure out what's wrong in my code, but failed.

Problem is when I start app, it's blank, nothing on emlutaor screen.

Help.
Here is my adapter class:

```
public class ImageButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ImageButton[] buttons;
public Context c;
public ImageButtonAdapter(Context c) {
    this.c = c;
    buttons = new ImageButton[9];
    for (int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
        buttons[i] = new ImageButton(c);
        buttons[i].setImageResource(R.mipmap.gmicon);
        buttons[i].setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300,300));
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button btn = (Button)v;
                btn.setText("5");
            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Here is gameActivity:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
    GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    ImageButtonAdapter adapter = new ImageButtonAdapter(this);
    gv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Anyone can help telling me what the problem is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to orverride getView() method For each item to show in gridView or listView.

refer this - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

```
 public class ImageButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   ImageButton[] buttons;
   public Context c;
   public ImageButtonAdapter(Context c) {
      this.c = c;
      buttons = new ImageButton[9];
  }


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return buttons.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = new ImageButton(c);
    buttons[position] = convertView;
    buttons[position].setImageResource(R.mipmap.gmicon);
    buttons[position].setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300,300));
    buttons[position].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button btn = (Button)v;
            btn.setText(position + "");
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make you getCount return `buttons.length`

```
@Override public int getCount()
  { 
    return buttons.length;
  }
```

Comment: Now I get error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.androidassignment,PID: 10879
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference